# difference between – initWithRequest:delegate: and +connectionWithRequest:delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know the difference between `–initWithRequest:delegate:` and `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` of `NSURLConnection`?

Just the first one is no-aotorelease object and  second is `autorelease`?

I want to know which one should I use in my ios code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already pointed out the difference

For iOS codes, it's best to use use Alloc/init rather than convenience auto release functions because they stay around after you are done using them and there is no way for you to release them

Use autorelease when it's not possible to know when to call release (such as when you are returning a object that is not being retained elsewhere) The closest autorelease pool will free the memory the next time the pool is drained.

If you do use alloc/init, remember to call release, otherwise it will linger on in the memory

Answer (score 1):

All methods in Objective-C that starts with `init` require to be called only after `alloc` method. Also init-method returns non-autoreleased object.

All methods that starts from name similar to class name, for example, `[NSString string]`, `[NSArray array]` and others returns `autoreleased` objects and don't require precalled `alloc` method.

Returning to you question: you can use any of that approaches: `alloc + initWithRequest:delegate:` or `connectionWithRequest:delegate:` but be sure to `release` object in first case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pointed out the only difference.

I use the +connectionWithRequest:delegate: method

I think something internal is retaining the connection until it fails or finishes